# Data lost after redis server restart

Tags: redis

Im using redis 2.8.3 server to store key value pairs in redis.

redis.conf

```
port 6378
bind 127.0.0.1
databases 16
```

After restarting the redis-server

```
  redis-server /home/redis.conf
```

Im loosing all the keys which i have already stored in redis.Can anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: look for "dump.rdb" file in the redis installation directory. That file is where your data is stored. Maybe you have some permissions issue, in that case redis log would help you.

Comment: Post your redis.conf please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run a 'BGSAVE' before you shut down the server does that help?

The shutdown script should always run that....

Answer (score 0):

Use this configuration settings, which will help you to sync data using a background process:

```
# appendfsync always
appendfsync everysec
# appendfsync no
```

Answer (score 0):

to prevent removing data from redis after restarting redis service in `windows`, you should update `redis.windows-service.conf`.
Redis `SAVE` command is used to create backup of current redis database

**Save the DB on disk**: `save` `seconds` `changes`

> Will save the DB if both the given number of seconds and the given
> number of write operations against the DB occurred

In the example below the behaviour will be to save:

1. after 1sec  if at least 1 key changed
2. after 100sec  if at least 50 keys changed

like in the following example, in `SNAPSHOTTING` section:

```
################################ SNAPSHOTTING  ################################
save 1 1
save 100 50
```

after making changes, `restart redis service`,
you can download last version of redis for [windows](https://github.com/tporadowski/redis/releases)